# Manipulating 'with' block at runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to create a testing framework that uses a 'with' block to run asserts, e.g.:

```
def test():
    stack = stack()
    stack.push('a')
    with expectations():
        not stack.empty()
        len(stack) == 2
```

When `test` is being called, the `with expectations()` block will actually run something similar to

```
assert eval('not stack.empty()')
assert eval('len(stack) == 2')
```

I've considered doing it by using a decorator for the test method itself that will transform the whole function before execution, but I would like to know if there is a way only do that when I execute the 'with' statement by running some code in the `__enter__` method of the `expectations` object. Something in the works of:

```
def __enter__(self):
    # get parent frame with inspect
    # get the block code that forms the 'with' statement
    # run 'assert eval(...)' for each line the block
    # skip actual execution of the block
```

Is it possible? Is it better in some way then manipulating method before execution in a decorator?

Comment: `with` only can *notify a context manager* of when a block is entered and exited, and when exiting, if an exception was raised. It cannot alter how code is interpreted. So the answer really is *no*.

Comment: Specifically, you cannot prevent the suite under `with` from being executed.

Comment: Last but not least, the Python philosophy includes *explicit is better than implicit*; I'd say your approach is violating that principle. Just use explicit assertions.

Comment: What makes your approach better than simple `assert`?

Comment: I try to bring some functionality from Groovy's [spock](https://code.google.com/p/spock/wiki/SpockBasics) framework, which is so far the best testing framework I worked with when it comes to readability.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, what actually happens when the interpreter comes across a 'with' statement? Does it create a new frame for the block of code to be executed in the with statement? Or it only notifies the context manager?

Comment: @Luftzig: no frame is created. It only notifies the context manager. Frames are only created when calling a function (with class bodies and comprehensions treated as function bodies).